# Vagrant on Windows 7 64bit: Could not match ? at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/default.pp:2 on node lucid32.hsd1.ca.comcast.net

Tags: windows-7, lamp, host, vagrant

Attempting to Boot and provision a LAMP VM with Vagrant and Virtual box running on a Windows 7 64 bit host. But am getting the error message:

```
Could not match ? at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/default.pp:2 on node lucid32.hsd1.ca.comcast.net.
```

Searches don't find any helpful clues - they are unrelated to using Vagrant and discuss completely different scenarios.

```
C:\Users\rdavis\lamp-project>vagrant up
[default] VM already created. Booting if it's not already running...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] -- 80 => 8080 (adapter 1)
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
[default] VM booted and ready for use!
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- v-root: /vagrant
[default] -- configs: /configs
[default] -- manifests: /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests
[default] Running provisioner: Vagrant::Provisioners::Puppet...
[default] Running Puppet with /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/default.pp...
stdin: is not a tty
Could not parse for environment production: Could not match ? at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/default.pp:2 on node lucid32.hsd1.ca.comcast.net.

The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

cd /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests && puppet apply /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/default.pp --detailed-exitcodes || [ $? -eq 2 ]

C:\Users\rdavis\lamp-project>
```

(A sub question, out of curiosity is: What is `lucid32.hsd1.ca.comcast.net` ?! This looks like a valid URL (but doesn't actually work (404)) - So what's it for?)

My setup:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Installed VirtualBox
- Installed Vagrant
- Installed Puppet: https://downloads.puppetlabs.com/windows/
- Installed Ruby: http://rubyinstaller.org/

Issued command:

```
vagrant box add base http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid32.box
```

Then attempted to setup a LAMP VM in a Windows 7 64 bit host based on:
http://ox86.tumblr.com/post/23734821654/painless-development-environments-with-virtualbox

...as follows:

```
mkdir lamp-project
cd lamp-project
C:\Users\rdavis\lamp-project>mkdir configs
C:\Users\rdavis\lamp-project>mkdir manifests
C:\Users\rdavis\lamp-project>vagrant init
```

Edited Vagrantfile inserted the following directly after `Vagrant::Config.run do |config|`

```
config.vm.box = “lucid32”
config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
   puppet.manifests_path = File.expand_path(“../manifests”, __FILE__)
end
config.vm.forward_port 80, 8080
config.vm.share_folder “configs”, “/configs”, File.expand_path(“../configs”, __FILE__)
```

Then created a `default.pp` puppet file (again, from reference [1](http://ox86.tumblr.com/post/23734821654/painless-development-environments-with-virtualbox) ) and put in the `manifests` folder as that reference [1](http://ox86.tumblr.com/post/23734821654/painless-development-environments-with-virtualbox) instructs

```
$config_path = "/configs”
$vagrant_base_path = "/vagrant”
Exec { path => "/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin” }
group { "puppet”: ensure => present }
exec { "apt-get update”: command => "apt-get update” }
class apache {
    file { "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default":
        ensure => file,
        source => "${config_path}/000-default",
        before => Service["apache2"],
    }
    exec { "enable-mod_rewrite":
        require => Package["apache2"],
        before => Service["apache2"],
        command => "/usr/sbin/a2enmod rewrite"
    }
    package { "apache2":
        ensure => present,
        before => File["/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default"],
    }

    service { "apache2":
        ensure => running,
        require => Package["apache2"]
    }
}
class php {
    package { "libapache2-mod-php5": ensure => present }
    package { "php5": ensure => present }
    package { "php5-cli": ensure => present }
    package { "php5-dev": ensure => present }
    package { "php5-mysql": ensure => present }
    package { "php-pear": ensure => present }
    exec { "pear upgrade":
        command => "/usr/bin/pear upgrade",
require => Package["php-pear"],
    }
}
class mysql {
  package { "mysql-server":
    require => Exec["apt-get update"],
    ensure => present,
  }
  service { "mysql":
    enable => true,
    ensure => running,
    require => Package["mysql-server"],
  }
  exec { "Set MySQL server root password":
        require => Package["mysql-server"],
        unless => "/usr/bin/mysqladmin -uroot -proot status",
        command => "/usr/bin/mysqladmin -uroot password root",
  }
}
include apache
include php
include mysql
```

**Updated**
Some invalid quoting e.g. see line `$vagrant_base_path = "/vagrant”`

All instances of `”` have been corrected to `"`

Comment: Why was this given a negative vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some invalid quoting e.g. see line $vagrant_base_path = "/vagrant”

All instances of ” have been corrected to "